# Extract a csv of heroku table - postgresql table size larger than database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have run

```
heroku pg:psql -a appname -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM listings) TO listings.csv CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER"
```

expecting a dump of the `listings` table.

Instead, the file keeps growing and growing, and is (somewhat illogically) larger than the entire app database obtained through

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
```

Which is confusing.

I am trying to simply make a `csv` copy of a table from a rails app in heroku.

Comment: I never really paid much attention to disk usage, but after a short research I believe PostgreSQL compresses its data: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-toast.html

Comment: @JimJones Looks like you're spot on. When the data finally extacted, it was ~14gb (but less than 1 inside the db)

Comment: I recall also being surprised after importing XML data into the database - it also got much smaller - but I never compared plain text imports +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`TOAST documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html), PostgreSQL applies some compression techniques to the data storage:

> The compression technique used for either in-line or out-of-line
>   compressed data is a fairly simple and very fast member of the LZ
>   family of compression techniques. See src/common/pg_lzcompress.c for
>   the details.